# JavaScript: Prevent a button from being pressed before entire page is loaded

Tags: javascript, button

How can I prevent users from pressing my web-page buttons before the page is fully loaded?

i.e.
I have a button that opens a lightbox. The JS for the lightbox is loaded last in the page for quicker response time. So if the user presses the button before the page is fully loaded - he either gets a JS error or the lightbox data is opened on a blank page.

I'm using Javascript with MooTools.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If I understand correctly neither

```
<body onload="...">
```

nor

```
$('#yourButton')...
```

guarantees that the document has finished loading. The (jQuery) method that does:

```
$(document).ready(function() { 
    $('#yourButton').attr("disabled", false); 
});
```

Comment: Use `window.addEvent('domready')` to ensure that the DOM has loaded.

Answer (score 2):

Make your button disabled. After the page is loaded - make it enabled

Here is a JQuery(sorry for not being "clean" Javascript example)

```
$('#yourButton').attr("disabled", false);
```

Answer (score 0):

here's an example:

```
<body onload="document.getElementById('button1').disabled=false">
  <button id="button1" disabled="1">
    ok
  </button>
<body>
```